# Cards are shrinking instead of overflowing on medium and small screen devices

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have 4 cards that I want to display on a screen, for large screen devices and above it's fine. But for medium screen devices I want to show 2 cards at a time and create an overflow-x, but rather than overflowing, the width of the cards is decreasing.

**ServiceCard.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export const ServiceCard = ({ imageUrl, heading, description }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col 2xl:h-28 xl:h-24 2xl:w-[14.5em] xl:w-[12em] lg:w-[11em] md:w-[21em] bg-cyan p-2 rounded-lg">
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center px-2">
        <img src={imageUrl} alt={heading} className="lg:w-8 xl:w-10"/> {/* Use the imageUrl prop */}
        <div className="2xl:ml-4 ml-2 font-bold 2xl:text-[15px] xl:text-[11px] lg:text-[11px]">{heading}</div> {/* Use the heading prop */}
      </div>
      <div className="mt-2 2xl:text-[10.5px] xl:text-[8px] lg:text-[7px] px-2">
        {description} {/* Use the description prop */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**ServicesProvided.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ServiceCard } from './ServiceCard';

export const ServicesProvided = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row gap-x-6 ml-14 overflow-auto">
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="./doctor.png"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="./doctor.png"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="./doctor.png"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="./doctor.png"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want cards size to be this and for next 2 cards, I want them to overflow horizontally
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhXCz.png)

[But this is what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbcLa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Flex children have `flex-shrink: 1` applied by default. This will mean that when there is not enough space along the main flex direction, they will attempt to shrink in that particular axis to try to avoid overflow.

To override this behavior such that the children will overflow and thus make the parent scrollable, consider applying `flex-shrink: 0` via the `shrink-0` utility class to avoid the shrinking:

```js
const ServiceCard = ({ imageUrl, heading, description }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col 2xl:h-28 xl:h-24 2xl:w-[14.5em] xl:w-[12em] lg:w-[11em] md:w-[21em] bg-cyan p-2 rounded-lg shrink-0">
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center px-2">
        <img src={imageUrl} alt={heading} className="lg:w-8 xl:w-10"/> {/* Use the imageUrl prop */}
        <div className="2xl:ml-4 ml-2 font-bold 2xl:text-[15px] xl:text-[11px] lg:text-[11px]">{heading}</div> {/* Use the heading prop */}
      </div>
      <div className="mt-2 2xl:text-[10.5px] xl:text-[8px] lg:text-[7px] px-2">
        {description} {/* Use the description prop */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const ServicesProvided = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row gap-x-6 ml-14 overflow-auto">
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="https://picsum.photos/40/40"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="https://picsum.photos/40/40?"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="https://picsum.photos/40/40?0"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
      <ServiceCard
        imageUrl="https://picsum.photos/40/40?1"
        heading="Top Rated Doctors"
        description="Find and book appointment with best medical professional in town"
      />
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<ServicesProvided/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```